# How to receive data sent by connected WiFi module/router on iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, wifi-direct

I want to develop an iOS app that continuously receives binary data from and I need to transfer show it in app lively.

By googling I received following code to make connection :

```
let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: "SSID Name", passphrase: "12345678", isWEP: false)

    configuration.joinOnce = true  
    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            if error?.localizedDescription == "already associated."
            {
                self.connectionLabel.text = "Connected"
            }
            else{
                self.connectionLabel.text = "Not Connected"
            }
        }
        else {
            self.connectionLabel.text = "Connected"
        }
    }`
```

**Problems:**

1. By using above code I am able to connect with WiFi Module/Router but connnection is breaking in some time?
2. I am first time working on networking app so I don't know how to receive data sent by WiFi Module/Router and how to get it realtime?

While answering please note that I am new to networking app in iOS.

Comment: connection breaking? does it disconnect? if yes, how you detect the connection lost?

Comment: Yes, It is disconnecting. I detected from my iPhone's setting -> Wifi -> Connection's list.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find any tutorial guide on this? Please help me if you have done this Raghvendra bhai...

Answer (score 0):

App is Disconnect because you have set `joinOnce` to `true`. As per apple docs:

When `joinOnce` is set to true, the hotspot remains configured and connected only as long as the app that configured it is running in the foreground. The hotspot is disconnected and its configuration is removed when any of the following events occurs:

- The app stays in the background for more than 15 seconds.
- The device sleeps.
- The app crashes, quits, or is uninstalled.
- The app connects the device to a different Wi-Fi network.
- The user connects the device to a different Wi-Fi network.

To disconnect the device from a hotspot configured with joinOnce set to true, call [`removeConfiguration(forSSID:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866727-removeconfigurationforssid).

If you want to connect to that network, ignore [`joinOnce`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration/2887518-joinonce) & [`lifeTimeInDays`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration/2866670-lifetimeindays) properties (do not set).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please guide me to receive data from wifi module once connection is establish.

Comment: are you trying to create File transfer app using WiFi?

Comment: may be [this](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/tutorials/multipeer-connectivity/), [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-file-sharing-using-wifi) may help.

Comment: No, I am not making any file transfer app. Actually, I have a hardware which is sending data only through WiFi module. I need to stream and see data live.